# Problems with plotting in Nested for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot in a nested loop, I expect three different plots with a different colors.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
    
Temp = np.array([6, 7, 8])
Freq = np.arange(1, 10, 0.1)
 
# nested for loop for 3 plots
for T in Temp:
        for f in Freq:
            def quanta(f,T):
                return(f*T)
            final = quanta(f,T)  
            plt.plot(f, final)
             
plt.show()
```

Comment: move the `plt.show()`inside the for loop just after the `plt.plot`

Answer (score 1):

one possibility is to use the subplot() function to provide three subplots. I made an adaptation in the code and from what I understand of the question, I believe it can answer you:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Temp = np.array([6, 7, 8])
Freq = np.arange(1, 10, 0.1)
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']

for i, T in enumerate(Temp):
    final = []
    for f in Freq:
        def quanta(f,T):
            return(f*T)
        final.append(quanta(f,T))
    plt.subplot(3, 1, i+1)
    plt.plot(Freq, final, color=colors[i])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks but I did not want subplots, so I tried the same code but using for i, T in enumerate(Temp):, I get the plot in different colour but legends now are in the same colour